# Using java reflection to unit test that a specific class is used in a method implementation

Tags: java, unit-testing, reflection

I want to implement and unit test a method that aggregates some data using Java 8 Stream API (the Stream interface and Collectors class). See the code below:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class AggregationKata {

    public static Map<String, Double> getAverageGradeByDepartment(Stream<Student> students) {

        return students
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getDepartment,
                        Collectors.averagingDouble(Student::getGrade)));

    }
}
```

I want to write a unit test that will enforce using the Stream API while implementing this method. In other words, Stream interface and Collectors class must be used. I guess I need to use java reflection in my unit test, but I cannot figure out how.

The question is - how do I write such a unit test? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to test that?  Normally one only needs to test two things: (1) does the method return the correct result, and (2) does it run fast enough.  And in most cases, #2 is unnecessary.

Comment: Answer : you do not write such a test. Oliver is spot on.

Comment: Surely the fact that your method takes a `Stream` as input suggests that it has to use the `Stream` API, no?

Comment: to Oliver Charlesworth: Thanks for the comment! I agree that what I am trying to do is rather specific. I am just creating a coding kata on java 8 streams and I want to enforce the use of stream API.

Comment: to Joe C: Yes, passing a Stream as a parameter does the job. But I just wanted to know if I pass an array instead, is there a way to test for using streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is not a unit test.
You don't want to test the behavior of your class.
You want ensure that the implementation follows a specific coding rule.

To address this requirement, you should rather define a rule in a tool designed to handle it (for example Sonar) or even a static Code Analysis tools in Jenkins at each commit.

By implementing a custom rule in Sonar, you use reflection and inspection of the source code but not directly (the API does the job for you).

For example :

```
@Override
public void visitNode(Tree tree) {
  MethodTree method = (MethodTree) tree;
  if (method.parameters().size() == 1) {
    MethodSymbol symbol = method.symbol();
    reportIssue(method.simpleName(), "Never do that!");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reflection can not access methods bodies. So it can't be used enforce specific implementations.

The only way to analyse the methods bodies is source code analysis (a parser + constraints), or if the code is already compiled byte code analysis.

So use a parser for java and implement the necessary constraints you want; or use a byte code tool like asm.

In my opinion byte code analysis is easier than source code, so i would use asm.

Here rather primitice example of how it could look, that code will print `[java/util/stream/Collectors::groupingBy, java/util/stream/Stream::collect, java/util/stream/Collectors::averagingDouble]` for your example. (Requires org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.2)

```
public static class MethodsCalledClassVisitor extends ClassVisitor {
    private Set<String> methodsCalled = new HashSet<>();

    public MethodsCalledClassVisitor() {
        super(Opcodes.ASM5);
    }

    @Override
    public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc, String signature, String[] exceptions) {
        if ("getAverageGradeByDepartment".equals(name)) {
            return new MyMethodVisitor(this);
        } else {
            return super.visitMethod(access, name, desc, signature, exceptions);
        }
    }

    public void addMethodCalled(String methodCall) {
        methodsCalled.add(methodCall);
    }

    public Set<String> getMethodsCalled() {
        return methodsCalled;
    }
}

public static class MyMethodVisitor extends MethodVisitor {
    private final MethodsCalledClassVisitor visit;

    public MyMethodVisitor(MethodsCalledClassVisitor visit) {
        super(Opcodes.ASM5);
        this.visit = visit;
    }

    @Override
    public void visitMethodInsn(int opcode, String owner, String name, String desc, boolean itf) {
        visit.addMethodCalled(owner + "::" + name);
        super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, desc, itf);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ClassReader reader = new ClassReader(AggregationKata.class.getName());

    MethodsCalledClassVisitor classVisitor = new MethodsCalledClassVisitor();
    reader.accept(classVisitor, 0);
    System.out.println(classVisitor.getMethodsCalled());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tool suggestion! I will look into it!